# Does a 301 redirect at the server level work when the host of the new website is different from the old one's?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

We are doing a site migration. the URL path and the protocol will change. Also we will move the website to a new server host. The web agency says that they will do the 301 redirects in server level and then delete the old website after launching the new one.

Is this way ok for transferring the SEO value to the new website?

Comment: Which server are the redirects getting implemented on, the old server or the new?

Comment: in the new server.

Comment: To clarify, the _hostname_ (ie. the domain) remains the same presumably? Just the physical server that the site is hosted on changes?

Comment: yeah the domain name stays the same but the physical server will change.

Answer (score 1):

Having the 301s on the new server should do the trick! Requests for the old URLs on the new server would then be redirected to the new pages, if the redirects are added in correctly.